# Find a rectangular equation for the conic.

Tags: calculus

$$x=2+\cos(\theta), y=3 \sin( \theta)-1.$$

This is how the problem was assigned, I'm confused and think the $y$ and $x$ should be $r$? also I'm not sure how to convert the separate equations for a limacon into one, or if thats what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

You know one identity: $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta=1$. Therefore, isolate $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, respectively, and substitute in that expression. Conclude from that what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
\cos\theta=x-2,\quad \sin\theta=\frac{y+1}{3},
$$
it follows from the well-known identity $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$ that
$$
(x-2)^2+\frac{(y+1)^2}{9}=1.
$$